# NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'text' was called on null. The getter 'text was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: text

Tags: flutter, dart

Shown Error: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'text' was called on null. 
 The getter 'text was called on null. 
 Receiver: null 
 Tried calling: text

How to create getter that get each controller value from the constructor?
so that I can call it in the TextFormField

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class CustomTextFieldForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hintText;
  final String errorMessage;

  const CustomTextFieldForm({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.errorMessage,
    required Null Function(dynamic text) onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CustomTextFieldFormState createState() => _CustomTextFieldFormState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldFormState extends State<CustomTextFieldForm> {
  get controller => null;

  get errorMessage => null;

  get hintText => null;

  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(

      controller: controller,
      validator: (String? value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return errorMessage;
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
          ),
          errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
          suffixIcon: controller.text.length > 0 ? IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.clear();
                setState(() {});
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.grey))
              : null
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're trying to get the text from the widget constructor, which you set to a return of type `Null`, so normally it will throw a `null`.

what you need to do to make it work :

change this :

```
    required Null Function(dynamic text) onChanged,
```

with this

```
    required this.onChanged,
```

then declare that `onChanged` function with other variables

```
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hintText;
  final String errorMessage;
  final Function(dynamic) onChanged;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `widget.variable_name` to access variable from `statefulWidget` class to `state` class.

```dart
TextEditingController get controller => widget.controller;

String get errorMessage => widget.hintText;

String get hintText => widget.errorMessage;
```

Comment: It has an error :  When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      WidgetInspectorService.toObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:1330:7)
#1      WidgetInspectorService.setSelectionById (package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:1450:25)
#2      WidgetInspectorService._registerServiceExtensionWithArg.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:882:35)
#3      BindingBase.registerServiceExtension.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:855:32)
<asynchronous suspension>